# Is there a situation where a player has a right to act even though all the bets are equalized

Tags: texas-hold-em

I am trying to understand the end condition for a betting round action. Can we say it's when the all the bets are equal for all involved players in the hand. With one exception of Preflop BB has a right to act.

So there are 2 conditions for betting to be over:

1. All bets are equal
2. All players have acted once.

Comment: Yes this is correct.

Comment: The exception here is when a player straddles. It often takes place in cash games where a player, usually the UTG player ( but other formats of the straddle allow players in later positions to make the straddle), will put out a blind raise before he sees his cards where he's effectively buying the button and is last to act and will have the option to check, if no one raised before him, or raise. You can effectively treat the straddler as a new big blind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close, but I would describe it this way:

The betting round is over when:

A. There is only one player with a live hand.

-- OR --

B.

```
1. Every player has acted at least once,
   -- AND --
2. Every player with a live hand has either matched the maximum bet or gone all in.
```

Answer (score 0):

Players can only bet once per round unless their bet is raised. The only exception is the big blind preflop, since he's never really had a turn to act